# data points and straight lines in Line Chart

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

- I am infant to power bi , And Below is the data which resembles to my
  data set in Power BI

[image]

- And below is result for the above data table

[image]

- But my client wan'ts the dot lines in it and he is expecting the
  report result to be as below

[image]

Can any one please help me how can I make it

Comment: You'll need to unpivot your dataset. Power Query has a built-in unpivot operation. Start there and let us know (sharing your code and attempts) where you find issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First unpivot the Quarter columns:

```
-Click 'Edit Queries' at the top
-Select "Transform' tab
-Select the 4 quarter columns (Select 1st column, shift click last column to selct them
-Select 'Unpivot Columns'
-Back to home tab, close and apply
```

Now add a line chart visual. Place the new column (Which depicts the quarter) in the 'Axis' field. Place the values for the companies in the Values field.